# sub2ind all x and y coordinates of a matrix

Tags: matrix, matlab

I am a quite newbie on matlab and i have a simple issue that is disturbing me,

I want to know if its possible to covert all the subscripts of a matrix to linear indices.

when using SUB2IND i must inform de x and y coordinates, but i want to convert all at the same time.

i can use function FIND which returns two vectors x and y and this way i can use SUB2IND succesfully, but FIND only returns the x and y coordinates of nonzero elements.

is there a smart way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want all of the elements of an array `A` as linear subscripts, this can be done simply via:

```
IND = 1:numel(A);
```

This works for any size or dimension array.

More on [array indexing in Matlab](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/matrix-indexing.html), including the difference between linear indexing and logical indexing. When you use `find` you're essentially using logical indexing to obtain linear indexing. The `find` function can be used to reliably obtain all of your linear indices, via `IND = find(A==A);`, but this is horrendously inefficient.

Answer (score 1):

you don't need to *convert*, just use a single number \ 1-D vector when accessing elements of your matrix. For example, given a 5x5 matrix `M`

```
M=magic(5);
```

you can access the last element using  `M(5,5)` or using `M(25)` ...

similarly `M(21:25)` will give you the info of `M(1,5)`,`M(2,5)`,...`M(5,5)`.

Comment: @horchler where does it say "logical subscripts"?

Comment: @EitanT: The question refers to linear indices - that's the point. And natan has since completely rewritten his answer which originally used `ones` to obtain a set of logical indices.

Comment: @horchler Ah, didn't see that.

Comment: I actually changed that as soon as I wrote the answer ... the response time of the guys here is phenomenal...

Comment: I've deleted that comment as it no longer makes sense or is helpful.